# How to call a function in a CommonJs module from a string

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs

I've read in a post somewhere that it can be achieved by using `eval` function, but the author also warned against using it.  I don't know if it matters, but I'm using browser and webpack. How would you do this?

```
const init = (fname) => {
   console.log(fname); //'myFunction'
   // How do I call myFunction from string here?
};

const myFunction = () => {};

module.exports = {
    init
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to map a function name to the actual function.

```
const functionMap = {myFunction};

const init = (fname) => {
   console.log(fname); //'myFunction'
   functionMap[fname]() // call functionMap.myFunction
};



const myFunction = () => {};

module.exports = {
    init
};
```

Comment: thank you, sir! It works, but I'm wondering if there's something like a namespace where local module functions are referenced.

Comment: That's dangerous - you should explictly define what other people can call. If you really want to, use the ```global``` variable: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global